# Keybord problem

Tags: 14.04

New to 14.04 have choosed french for operating language. Everything went well at the start but now system switched to english keyboard for unknown reasons. How can I fix it to french by default ?

Answer (score 0):

Open System Settings and choose "Keyboard layout". There you can set the French keyboard as default and possibly delete the English keyboard layout altogether. It also shows a key combination to switch from one layout to another.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Ubuntu

Your problem is simple at the top right you might see some icons basically choose the text one and click on it then text entry settings then add the keyboard layout you want and u can even delete the whole english layout of you want

And you're good to go!

Answer (score 0):

In 14.04, you'll have to go to **Keyboard** then **Text Entry** (at the bottom of the configuration window), then add French, and delete English.

Bonne chance :)